# How to change indentation of while loop in embedded pseudo algorithm?

Tags: indentation, algorithmicx

I am writing an algorithm, which has some sub-algorithms, and I want to have all in one pesudocode. How can I do this (manage the indention)?

As long as I am using `\State`, I can use `\hspace{\algorithmicindent}` and it works, but I can not change the indention of while loop. I want while to be exactly at the same indent as the previous line. You can find my code in the following:

```
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{my algorithm}
  \label{myalgorithm}
  \textbf{Input:} All paths\\
  \textbf{Output:} Best path.
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \State $CurrentSelectedPath \gets \{\}$
    \State\textbf{sub-algorithm}
    \Statex\hspace{\algorithmicindent} $h\gets \text{allPossible}$
    \While{condition}
      \State text
    \EndWhile
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define an appropriate grouping for your sub-algorithm. Here's the way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,amsmath}

\algnewcommand{\algorithmicsubalgorithm}{\textbf{sub-algorithm}}
\algdef{SE}[SUBALG]{SubAlgorithm}{EndSubAlgorithm}{\algorithmicsubalgorithm}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicsubalgorithm}%
%\algtext*{EndSubAlgorithm}% If you want to avoid seeing "end sub-algorithm"

\algnewcommand{\algorithmicinput}{\textbf{Input:}}
\algnewcommand{\algorithmicoutput}{\textbf{Output:}}
\algnewcommand\Input{\item[\algorithmicinput]}%
\algnewcommand\Output{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}%

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{my algorithm}
  \textbf{Input:} All paths \\
  \textbf{Output:} Best path.
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \State $\text{CurrentSelectedPath} \gets \{\}$
    \State\textbf{sub-algorithm}
    \Statex \hspace{\algorithmicindent} $h \gets \text{allPossible}$
    \While{condition}
    \State text
    \EndWhile
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{my algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \Input All paths.
    \Output Best path.
    \State $\text{CurrentSelectedPath} \gets \{\}$
    \SubAlgorithm
      \State $h \gets \text{allPossible}$
      \While{condition}
        \State text
      \EndWhile
    \EndSubAlgorithm
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The new block is denoted by `\SubAlgorithm`...`\EndSubAlgorithm` (the end-clause can be avoided/removed by uncommenting the appropriate piece of code). It would be possible to make `\SubAlgorithm` take an argument that could be used as the descriptor for the sub-algorithm, say.

You'll notice that I also took the liberty of cleaning up some other content in your algorithm; this should provide some consistent look-and-feel, and also be easier to update.

---

Here is an implementation that allows you to name the `\SubAlgorithm{<name>}`...`\EndSubAlgorithm` section:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,amsmath}

\algnewcommand{\algorithmicsubalgorithm}{\textbf{sub-algorithm}}
\algdef{SE}[SUBALG]{SubAlgorithm}{EndSubAlgorithm}[1]{\algorithmicsubalgorithm\ \textsc{#1}}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicsubalgorithm}%
%\algtext*{EndSubAlgorithm}% If you want to avoid seeing "end sub-algorithm"

\algnewcommand{\algorithmicinput}{\textbf{Input:}}
\algnewcommand{\algorithmicoutput}{\textbf{Output:}}
\algnewcommand\Input{\item[\algorithmicinput]}%
\algnewcommand\Output{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}%

\begin{document}


\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{my algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \Input All paths.
    \Output Best path.
    \State $\text{CurrentSelectedPath} \gets \{\}$
    \SubAlgorithm{First}
      \State $h \gets \text{allPossible}$
      \While{condition}
        \State text
      \EndWhile
    \EndSubAlgorithm
    \SubAlgorithm{Second}
      \State $h \gets \text{allPossible}$
      \While{condition}
        \State text
      \EndWhile
    \EndSubAlgorithm
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @izi: No. You can use as many `\SubAlgorithm`...`\EndSubAlgorithm` constructions in your `algorithmic` environment as you wish. It would be possible to adapt the definition of `\SubAlgorithm{<arg>}` to take an argument `<arg>` so you could perhaps do `\SubAlgorithm{First}`...`\EndSubAlgorithm` ... `\SubAlgorithm{Second}`...`\EndSubAlgorithm` ... in the same `algorithmic` environment. Is this what you're after?

Comment: yes, I want to know how can I define an argument for \SubAlgorithm as its name, so that I can use it for different sub algorithms?

Comment: @izi: I've added an argument to `\SubAlgorithm{<name>}` allowing you to name the sub-algorithm. The formatting is set to `\textsc{<name>}`, but you can change that.